# AWS Lambda function works fine first time but fails second time until I increase memory

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, timeout

I have a lambda function the process some data. When I invoke it it works fine the first time but when I try to invoke it again it timeouts. If I increased the amount of memory it works then timeouts if invoked it again.

I'm new to AWS, shouldn't the memory be cleared after the function is finished running on itself or should I do something to force it to be cleared out?

Comment: Well it depends on what your Lambda is doing but no, read https://stackoverflow.com/a/58693348/4800344

Comment: For a better assessment what happens to your AWS Lambda function, please post its code.

Comment: What does your code do? Is your function creating variables _outside_ of the function handler? You'll need to show some code or provide much more information for us to be able to assist you.